# Определить - является ли тип переменной указателем

Tags: c++, указатели, шаблоны-с++, инициализация

**Задача:** реализовать класс представляющий безопасный массив. Он должен: хранить информацию о количестве элементов, в случае выхода за границы - кидать исключения, а также при создании инициализировать все элементы значением по умолчанию.

**Что сделано:** я реализовал класс массива следующим образом:

```
#if !defined(ARRAY_WRAPPER_H)
#define ARRAY_WRAPPER_H

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template<class T> class ArrayWrapper {

    private:
        T* array;
        int size;

    public:
        ArrayWrapper(int size): size(size) {
            array = new T[size];
            for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) array[i] = 0;
        }

        ~ArrayWrapper() {
            delete [] array;
        }

        T get(int index) {
            if(index < 0 || index >= size) throw IndexOutOfBoundsException(index, size);
            return array[index];
        }

        void set(int index, T value) {
            if(index < 0 || index >= size) throw IndexOutOfBoundsException(index, size);
            array[index] = value;
        }

        int getSize() {
            return size;
        }

        class IndexOutOfBoundsException {
            private:
                string message;
            public:
                IndexOutOfBoundsException(int outIndex, int size) {
                    this->message = "Size array = " + to_string(size) + ". Your index = ";
                    this->message += to_string(outIndex);
                }

                string getMessage() {
                    return message;
                }
        };

};

#endif
```

**Что не получается:** проблемы возникли с последним требованием - инициализация массива значениями по умолчанию. Если в качестве аргумента шаблона передавать указатель на какой-то тип или одни из примитивов (например, 
`ArrayWrapper<int>, ArrayWrapper<MyClass*>`), то проблем нет. Для этих случаев инициализация по умолчанию таким способом:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) array[i] = 0;
```

работает. Но вот для случаев вроде этого - `ArrayWrapper<string>` я естественно получаю ошибку компиляции.

**Вопрос:** как сделать, чтобы строчка

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) array[i] = 0;
```

не выполнялась(или вообще отсутствовала) в случаях вроде ArrayWrapper. Если я не ошибаюсь - это должно делаться с помощью макросов, но как именно - не могу понять. Пожалуйста, помогите решить проблему.

Comment: [The rule of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь инициализацией для типов по умолчанию (не помню точно термин - нулевая инициализация, что ли...) - т.е.

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) array[i] = T{};
```

Для указателя будет `nullptr`, для строки - пустая строка, для `int` - нули...

Или - еще проще:

```
ArrayWrapper(int size): size(size) {
    array = new T[size]{};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Но вот для случаев вроде этого - ArrayWrapper< string > я естественно получаю ошибку компиляции.

Вам нужно реализовать специализацию шаблоного класса для типа `std::string`:

```
template<>
class ArrayWrapper<std::string> {
public:
    explicit ArrayWrapper(size_t size) {
        // do smth
    }    
};
```

Чтобы повторно не имплементировать методы вроде get/set, лучше вынести их реализацию в класс `ArrayWrapperBase` и сделать его базовым классом для `ArrayWrapper` и его специализаций.

*P.S. Если предполагается использовать данный контейнер для типов, имеющих констуктор по-умолчанию, вариант @Harry Вам подходит больше.*

Comment: Тем, кто ставит "минусы": если Вам кажется (или Вы уверены), что мой ответ содержит неточности или ошибки - добавьте комментарий с их описанием.

Comment: @isnullxbn, скажите пожалуйста - какие преимущества и недостатки имеет описанный вами способ в сравнении со способом описанным Harry?

Comment: @Bakuard, в общем случае преимуществ нет, в частном - возможны при условии наличия сложностей связанных с реализацией конструктора по умолчанию. Если планируется использовать данный класс как часть библиотеки - так же возможны кейсы для использования (вспомните про std::vector<bool>).